Could bacteria survive on a (highly contrived) neutron star?
Just a weird thought I had --
Typically, ordinary atomic matter can't withstand the conditions on the surface of a neutron star. Though heat is one obstacle, the main issue is of course the absurd pressures exerted by gravitational force.
But, what if, for whatever reason, a (thermally cold) neutron star was spun up to its mass-shedding limit? The net g-force on the equatorial cusp would by definition be zero. Tidal forces would preclude anything of macroscopic size, but the force across a single micrometer would be on the order of a few tens of g. Bacteria are known to survive uniform g-forces three orders of magnitude above this, but I'm unsure about the effect of differential forces here.
I'd also be curious about what role spin-down effects would play. Is it possible for a spinning neutron star to be non-magnetic? If not, how long would it take (order-of-magnitude) until the g-forces escalated above, say, 1 million g?

It's hard to imagine how such a star could be stable. If the gravitational forces at the surface were weakened to this point, the pressure would be way too low to sustain neutron degenerate matter and the star would explode.

Also I would recommend splitting this into two questions. The two parts are pretty different.

I doubt that additional angular momentum will make net g-force smaller on the surface, since you also need to include relativistic spinning effects which basically says that spinning object increases it's energy-mass and so this will curve space-time around rotating object more, which classically must reflect back as increased $g$ force.

based on this work, relativistic spinning objects can mass shed, implying the existence of a zero-g cusp. Also, regarding the forces at the surface -- this is only true at or very near the cusp. In effect, this region would be normal matter, while as the pressure increases (i.e. for essentially all of the rest of the star), matter would transition through white dwarf through to neutron star matter.

There is a lovely science fiction book named Dragon's Egg which attempted to delve into the idea of life evolving on a neutron star. While a different scenario than the one proposed it gives a much acclaimed exposition of life in extreme conditions (albeit, still some limits on its realism).
The astronomy stack exchange has some excellent answers about mass shedding on neutron stars which is helpful especially regarding neutron decay into protons and electrons in the region of low gravity.  This brings up an interesting idea of the regeneration of a star if one where to add enough rotational energy to the neutron star.
There is a realtively recent but lovely paper that explores starquakes and crack formation on rapidly spinning neutron stars which can then become gas filled from the surrounding material. This is highly speculative but starts giving an interesting set of information on the environment for the life you describe.
The hardest part is that the energy levels associated with the ejection of material are all highly relativistic (e.g. high energy).  Since ordinary biological life requires relatively low energy chemical bonds in order to exist it is very difficult to see how a complex molecule associated with ordinary life such as bacteria would not be broken up into magnetic goo by the intense radiation of the escaping gas.
What is interesting about your question is that there is fairly advanced research about implications of neutrino production in changing chirality of amino acids near supernova explosions to include cases where neutron stars are formed. The Supernova Amino Acid Processing model is a fascinating journey into how life and evolutionary processes could have been influenced by steller evolution, including effects of neutrinos generated by neutron stars.
Research into how bacteria develop energy shows a strong dependence on transfer of relatively low energy electrons as compared to the relativistic electrons that might be emitted as part of the formation of gas from starquakes on the neutron star. That said Deinococcus radiodurans is an extremiphile bacteria that is resistant to ionizing radiation.
Calculations regarding the intensity of radiation near a rotating neutron star are quite involved and the energies can be shown to be highly relativistic which basically dwarf the resistance of even the most resourceful extremophiles.
That said, I haven't given an explicit calculation and sadly based on above, to give an extremely satisfying one would be very involved, however from inspection of the extent literature I would feel comfortable stating that the radiation environment would be to extreme for ordinary biological life to survive long even if gravitational forces were subdued.

Thanks for the info -- to summarise the post and your links as best I understand, even cold neutron stars are going to have extreme radiation due to both magnetic field and gravitational relaxation? I do wonder if there is a possibility that a neutron star could have a low field / be fully relaxed, but I suppose that's a separate question. Also, thanks for the book recommendation, I've heard of Dragon's Egg but haven't gotten around to reading it yet!
